# Where to place the file for user registration form

Tags: template-override, registration

I'm creating a template override for the Joomla3.8 registration form.
Where should I upload the `default.php` file to?

This is where I've tried, without luck:
/templates/yootheme/html/com_users/registration

And:
/templates/yootheme/html/com_users/registration/tmpl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the first one is correct, but I am guessing the template name is wrong.  Generally YOOtheme names them yoo_name, so double check that.

/templates/yoo_templatename/html/com_users/registration/default.php

If you are using Yootheme Pro, then it does it's own thing and I believe you need a child theme instead.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out I had the wrong path name ...
It's working now!